# Visual Studio hangs on startup after I cancelled getting latest

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, freeze

I tried to map a workspace and started getting latest from it, the number of files to download were quite large, talking gigabytes.

Anyway I cancelled it halfway through as I needed to do a restart. Now when I launch VS (with or without a solution) it just hangs saying "Preparing solution" and a balloon pops up on the left saying its doing an internal operation.

I think its still trying to get latest in the background or connect to the workspace, how can I cancel this?

Comment: you might want to repair VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following (from fastest to the most thorough one).

- in windows explorer/dos prompt search for suo files and delete them (they are marked as hidden). Download all files from commandline or source control explorer. Open solution
- redo your steps, creating new workspace just don't cancel this time

Do note, if vs is hanged on something, make sure that no modal window is displayed, waiting for your input.